# Rollapply for backtesting the value at risk

Tags: r, time-series, rollapply, back-testing

I want to backtest the empirical (unconditional) value at risk of a time series vector:

```
x = rnorm(1000)
xt = diff(x)
quantile(xt,0.01)
```

So I am thinking that rollapply function in R might be helpful, since I want to roll estimate the quantile a from time t until the end time T with rolling window 100 by one observation.

If I code the following :

```
a = rollapply(xt,width=100,quantile(xt,probs=c(0.01)))
```

I receive an error:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'quantile(xt, probs = c(0.01))' is not a function, character or symbol
```

What I am doing wrong here ?

PLUS: How can I plot the two series (historical estimate and backtesting result) in one plot?

Comment: You have two separate questions here, but for your first I think you just need to specify the function and write it in the format of a function. `a = zoo::rollapply(xt, width=100, FUN = function(x) quantile(x, probs=c(0.01)))`

Comment: Very helpful comment.But how can I plot the two series ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Plotting is plotting (such as `plot(xt, a)`), but your first problem is that `a` will be a different *length* (900) than `xt` (999). Use `rollapply(...,partial=TRUE)` or `rollapply(...,fill=NA)` or something similar. From there, the question of plotting becomes much more approachable *to you*. (For me it's still too broad to be able to offer anything substantial.)

Comment: Other considerations: is this a forward-looking estimation or backward-looking? See another answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50014507/3358272) that demonstrates some `align`ment options.

Comment: @r2evans it is backtesting.you start say from index t=100 and you roll forward by 1 observation with moving window 100.I think @TrainingPizza the second plot must be `lines(a)` but I have no clue about the first plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert x to zoo series z and then use diff, rollapply and plot as shown.  cbind.zoo will align the series.  Note that rollapply uses centered windows.  If you want right aligned windows use rollapplyr with an r on the end instead.  If you want the series in a single panel add screen = 1 argument to plot.

```
library(zoo)

set.seed(123)

x <- rnorm(1000)
z <- zoo(x)
zt <- diff(z)
a <- rollapply(zt, 100, quantile, probs = 0.01)
plot(cbind(z, zt, a))
```

[image: screnshot]

Comment: I think it might be `plot(zt[100:1000],type="l")
lines(a)` in order to have the same length ? am I right ?

Comment: No. zoo automatically handles alignment.

Comment: How can I find how many mismatches are from this backtesting ?

Comment: What does mismatches mean?

Comment: The line a from rollapply that hit the zt.

Comment: This draws a red circle if zt is less or equal to than a.  `plot(cbind(zt, a, zt[zt <= a]), screen = 1, col = list(1, 1, 2), type = list("l", "l", "p"))`